# How to correctly implement 2d Vectors C++

Tags: c++, vector

Straight to it, I'm trying to add all the possible paths between two points for a chess piece to a 2d vector. Essentially having all the paths made in one structure, So that i can then go through that and determine the shortest path. I seem to be only adding the first vector and every other iteration of the process an empty vector is being added.

Note** in my code it shows "path.erase()" which i use to clear the vector so the next iteration receives an empty vector. I have used std::vector.clear() as well but the same outcome was given.

I don't have much experience with 2d vectors and feel like I'm accessing the 2d vector wrong. Hope to take on any advice or corrections necessary.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <random>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;    

class Piece {
private:
char type; //type or rank of piece (can be 'K' for "Knight" or 'O' for every other piece)
int x, y;
bool atFinish;
int movesMade;
int finalCount;
int visited[8][8]; //where '0' represents unvisited square and '1' represents visited
vector<string> path;
vector <vector<string> > possiblePaths;

public:
Piece(int xIn, int yIn, char typeIn) {
    x = xIn;
    y = yIn;
    movesMade = 0;
    finalCount = 100;
    type = typeIn;
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            visited[i][j] = 0;
        }
    }
}

bool canMove(int y, int x) {
    return ((x > 0 && x < 8) 
            && (y > 0 && y < 8)
            && (visited[y][x] == 0));
}

void move(int endY, int endX) {
    int preX, preY;
    vector<int> v;
    random_device rd;

    //Randomizing the possible moves for every new position the knight comes to
    //so as to not continually use the same sequence of moves at every new position
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        v.push_back(i);

    mt19937 g(rd());
    shuffle(v.begin(), v.end(), g);
    /*********************************************/

    if (x == endX && y == endY) {
        movesMade = 0;
    }
    else {
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            preX = x;
            preY = y;
            movePiece(v[i]);

            if (canMove(y, x)) {
                movesMade+= 1;
                visited[y][x] = 1;
                string pos = to_string(y) + to_string(x);
                path.push_back(pos);
                move(endY, endX);
            }
            else {
                y = preY;
                x = preX;
            }
            x = preX;
            y = preY;
        }
    }
}

void movePiece(int move) {
    switch (move) {
        case 0: //piece moves 'down' 2 and 'right' 1
            x += 1;
            y += 2;
            break;
        case 1: //piece moves 'down' 2 and 'left' 1
            x -= 1;
            y += 2;
            break;
        case 2: //piece moves 'up' 2 and 'right' 1
            x += 1;
            y -= 2;
            break;
        case 3: // piece moves 'up' 2 and 'left' 1
            x -= 1;
            y -=2;
            break;
        case 4: //piece moves 'left' 2 and 'down' 1
            x -= 2;
            y += 1;
            break;
        case 5: //piece moves 'left' 2 and 'up' 1
            x -= 2;
            y -= 1;
            break;
        case 6: //piece moves 'right' 2 and 'down' 1
            x += 2;
            y += 1;
            break;
        case 7: //piece moves 'right' 2 and 'up' 1
            x += 2;
            y -= 1;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}

void solution(int startY, int startX, int endY, int endX) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
        y = startY;
        x = startX;
        move(endY, endX);
        possiblePaths.push_back(path);
        path.erase(path.begin(), path.end());
    }

    //Error checking purposes, print size of 2d vector and all paths made
    cout << possiblePaths.size() << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < possiblePaths.size(); i++) {
        vector<string> v = possiblePaths[i];
        for (vector<string>::const_iterator j = v.begin(); j != v.end(); j++)
            cout << *j << " ";
        cout << "\n";
    }
}
};

int convertLetter(char letter) {
switch(letter) {
    case 'A':
        return 0;
    case 'B':
        return 1;
    case 'C':
        return 2;
    case 'D':
        return 3;
    case 'E':
        return 4;
    case 'F':
        return 5;
    case 'G':
        return 6;
    case 'H':
        return 7;
    case '1':
        return 7;
    case '2':
        return 6;
    case '3':
        return 5;
    case '4':
        return 4;
    case '5':
        return 3;
    case '6':
        return 2;
    case '7':
        return 1;
    case '8':
        return 0;
    default:
        return -1;
}
}

void play(string start, string end) {
int startX = convertLetter(start[0]);
int startY = convertLetter(start[1]);
int endY = convertLetter(end[1]);
int endX = convertLetter(end[0]);
Piece p(startY, startX, 'K');

p.solution(startY, startX, endY, endX);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
if ( argc != 3) // argc should be 3 for correct execution
    cout << "Invalid entry \n";
else {
    string start = argv[1];
    string end = argv[2];
    play(start, end);
}
}
```

Comment: Create an isolated example; this code depends on parts that are inaccesible for us.

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz how can i do that. not sure how to.

Comment: [Perhaps this will help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz please see edit. I read the link, personally i don't thing approx. 200 lines of code I've replaced the post with abides exactly by the instructions however it will provided an executable example.

Comment: It would be helpful if you added some comments to your code to highlight the parts that you have problems with. Sidenote: Parts of your code are unnecessarily verbose. For instance, the body of `convertLetter()` can be written like this: `if(letter >= 'A' && letter <= 'H') return letter - 'A'; if(letter >= '1' && letter <= '8') return '8' - letter; return -1;`

Comment: @ChrisDrew  I seem to be only adding the first vector and every other vector being added is empty.

Comment: @cmaster essentially i would be focusing on methods 'solution()' and 'move()' to uncover the problem in my code. And thank you for that side not i was not aware of that process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I fully understand your algorithm but did you intend to clear `visited` after finding a possible path? Something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {
  y = startY;
  x = startX;
  move(endY, endX);
  possiblePaths.push_back(path);
  path.erase(path.begin(), path.end());
  for(auto& v : visited) std::fill(std::begin(v), std::end(v), 0);
}
```

Otherwise it looks like subsequent searches are blocked because most positions are visited.